# How to remove/delete some SE sites from my profile?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I have a few Beta sites and low participation sites associated with my account that I would like to remove/delete.

*Martial Arts*

*Home Improvement*

How can I remove a couple of these sites without accidentally deleting my entire account/profile?

Comment: If you haven't actually interacted with anything on the site, there should be a 'Delete' link in your profile. Otherwise I think you have to contact SE.

Comment: Looks like you ended up deleting them all, hope it wasn't by mistake... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard this question again handles by contacting the community managers - not self delete.

Comment: @bonCodigo you can self delete only when the account has no real activity, e.g. votes ,posts etc. When you have those, it can be removed only by the team after you explicitly request it.

Comment: Yup that's what I am after, please see my question. *No/vee bit of activity* :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're worried about making a misstep, head to [our contact page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), there's a form there for handling account deletion ("I need to delete my profile"). You can either do this per account you want removed on each of those sites, or you can fill out the form in one place and explicitly state (and link to the profiles of) exactly the accounts you want removed using the free text space provided. We'll then handle the deletion according to your specifications.